# Add VMs and corresponding replications to VMGroups in a Hyper-V cluster

Tags: design-patterns, powershell

I'm looking for input on how to improve a powershell script I wrote.
Im especially looking for suggestions, that I might be able to apply to future projects as well. Like (anti-)patterns I'm not aware of and such.
General things like "too many small functions" vs "use more functions" or "better collect all info in a certain object type" and stuff like that is what im looking for.
If anyone has experience with the Cmd-lets I use and is willing to share, more specific suggestions are welcome aswell of course.

The script is used in a cluster of 4 HyperV hosts that each run about 30 Virtual Machines.
There is the concept of replication in Hyper-V. It works like this:
You can create a replication of a VM running on one Hyper-V server and have this replication running (in a shutdown state) on another Hyper-V server in the cluster.
I will call these two the **production-vm** and the **failover-vm** . If the failover is done then the former production-vm becomes the failover-vm and vice versa.
In theory there can be replications of replications and so on. The script has to be scheduled to run every so often, because where vms (and their replications) are located is somewhat dynamically - changes happen a few times a year.

The script is executed on a 5th server outside of the cluster.

The script should accomplish the following:

- take the name of a production-vm and lookup what the corresponding failover-vm is.
  This must work the other way around too!
- create a VMGroup on all Hyper-V hosts with a name that resembles the vm we were looking up
- add both the production-vm and the failover-vm to their groups.

  - since VMGroups are local to a Hyper-V host they can have the same name on all hosts but should usually contain either the **production-vm** or the **failover-vm** or **no vm** at all.

So here is the code:

```
# This script looks up VMs and their corresponding failover-vms (usually named xxx_replika) and adds them to VMGroups called LTR_<vmname>.
#

$LTR_VMs = $LTR_VMs = "VM-ELO01", "VM-FILE01", "VMs03", "VMs71", "VMs72", "VM-SBO02" 
$HVhosts = "hv01.example.com", "hv02.example.com", "hv05.example.com", "hv06.example.com"

function Get_VM_and_Replica_by_name_remote([array]$HVhosts, [String]$VMname) {
            $searchedVM = Get-VM -name $VMname -ComputerName $HVHosts
            $searchedReplica = Get-VMReplication -VM $searchedVM  ## can't get failoverVM directly since HyperV server A cannot authenticate vs HyperV server B
            #construction of an array to return both vm-objects to the caller:
            $searchedVM2 = Get_VM_by_VMReplication_remote -VMReplication $searchedReplica
            $bothVMs = @()
            $bothVMs += $searchedVM
            $bothVMs += $searchedVM2
            return ,$bothVMs
            ## returning to caller will 'deserialize' the vms in the array. This will be problematic later when we add those vm-objects to a VMGroup
        }

function Get_VM_by_VMReplication_remote($VMReplication) {
        # if this VMReplication-Object is a Primary, then get the VM-Object from the Replication Server (where the failover vm runs)
        if ($VMReplication.Mode -eq "Primary") {
            Invoke-Command -ComputerName $VMReplication.ReplicaServerName -ScriptBlock {
                $VM = Get-VM -Id $Using:VMReplication.Id
                $VM
            }
        }
        # if this VMReplication-Object is a Replica, then get the VM-Object from the Primary Server (where the production VM runs)
        if ($VMReplication.Mode -eq "Replica") {
            Invoke-Command -ComputerName $VMReplication.PrimaryServerName -ScriptBlock {
                $VM = Get-VM -Id $Using:VMReplication.Id
                $VM
            }
        }
}

function Create_GroupName([String]$VMName){
    $prefix = "LTR_"
    $Groupname = $prefix + $VMName 
    return $Groupname
}

function RemoveVMs_from_Group_remote([array]$HVhosts, [String]$GroupName) {

    foreach ( $HVhost in $HVhosts) {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $HVhost -ScriptBlock {

            $vms = (Get-VMGroup -Name $Using:GroupName).VMMembers
            foreach ($vm in $vms) {
                Remove-VMGroupMember -Name $Using:GroupName -VM $vm
            }
        }
    }
}

# add all VMs to group on their respective HVhost:
# must use Invoke-Command because of deserialization issue with vms in our array
function Add_VMs_to_VMGroup_remote([array]$VMs, [String]$Groupname) {
    foreach ( $VM in $VMs) {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $VM.ComputerName -ScriptBlock {
            $thisVM = Get-VM -Id $Using:VM.VMId
            Write-Host "adding $($thisVM.VMName) to Group $($Using:Groupname) on $($Using:VM.ComputerName)."
            Add-VMGroupMember -Name $Using:Groupname -vm $thisVM
        }
    }
}



foreach ($name in $LTR_VMs) {
    $vmPair = (Get_VM_and_Replica_by_name_remote -HVHosts $HVHosts -VMname $name )
    $myGroupName = Create_GroupName -VMName $name

    # make sure group exists on all HyperV-hosts:
    foreach ($HVhost in $HVHosts) {
        $VMGroupX = Get-VMGroup -Name $myGroupName -ComputerName $HVhost
        if (!$VMGroupX) {
            New-VMGroup -Name $myGroupName -ComputerName $HVhost -GroupType VMCollectionType
            Write-Host "Created group $myGroupName on $($HVhost)."
        }
    }

    RemoveVMs_from_Group_remote -HVHosts $HVHosts -Groupname $myGroupName
    Add_VMs_to_VMGroup_remote -VMs $vmPair -Groupname $myGroupName
}

#careful with vms with more than 1 replication like VMs33. Doesn't work fine because if you lookup the replicaname, you may get back two replicas and not the primary vm.
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Comment: @Mast thanks for your input. I edited the title accordingly